# Selenium Python - Multiprocessing Only Controlling One Browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm attempting to run a selenium script locally and open three non-headless browsers.  I'm using multiprocesing Pools (and have tried with just regular multiprocessing as well)  and come across an interesting issue where 3 browser sessions open, but only the first one actually navigates to the target_url and attempts control.  The other two just sit and wait and do nothing.

Here is the execution code that's relevant

```
    run_id = str(uuid.uuid4())



    options = Options()
    #options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium' #works for lambda
    start_time = time.time()

    options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome' #testing

    #options.add_argument('--headless') don't need headless
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--verbose')
    #options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')# test add
    options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
    options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
    options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
    #options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')# test add
    #options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") test remove
    #options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        #'/opt/chromedriver' not found
    logger.info("Before driver initiated")
    # job_id = event['job_id']
    # run_id = event['run_id']

    send_log(job_id, run_id, "JOB START", True, "", time.time() - start_time)

    retries = 0

    drivers = []





        try:

            #driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver_89', chrome_options=options)
            driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver90', chrome_options=options)
            #driver2 = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver90', chrome_options=options)

            break

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

            logger.info('exception with driver instantiation, retrying... ' + str(e))
            #time.sleep(5)
            driver = None

            driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)


   ....
```

and here is how i'm invoking each process

```
        
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=3)

for i in range(3):
    pool.apply_async(invoke, args=("https://macau-flash-sale.myshopify.com/",))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Is it possible that despite the multiple processes, selenium is not communicating with the other two browser instances properly?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Selenium isn't async. You want to switch to pyppeteer / python playwright

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with this,  Selenium CAN be used with async/multiprocessing.

But you cannot specify the same user/data directories for each session.  I had to remove these parameters so that each chrome session creates unique directories for iteself.

just remove the below and it'll work.

```
 options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')# test add
    options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think selenium can handle multiple browsers at once. I recommend writing 3 different python scripts and running them all at once through the terminal. If they need to communicate information to each other, probably the easiest way is to just get them to write to a text file.

Comment: Thanks for this,  that was my understanding as well!  I'm experiencing this issue even while running the exact same code as multiple scripts...

Comment: Upon further research you can control multiple browsers this way.  The issue was with specifying the same data/user dirs for each subprocess